# Tracking my run

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to track my run using MKMapView, as it is done in MapMyRun (http://www.mapmyrun.com/). I am having difficulty drawing my movements onto the mapView.

Can someone point me into the right direction please?

Comment: Also check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13599083/1032151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done similar application in BADA, not sure about iPhone yet but here is the logic that I had applied
1. Register for location service, with minimal time interval.
2. Start drawing using overlay. Draw line from your previous position to new position (initially both being same)
3. As soon as you get location update draw line again as above, update previous position to new position and continue.

Hope this is useful. Just will need to do iPhone specific code...

Comment: here is the link to help you about how to do it in iPhone
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002179/finding-path-route-between-two-points-on-mapkit-in-iphone/12002857#12002857