# Path tracing in map view using GPS in ios6

Tags: iphone, dictionary, path, trace

in my mapview using gps, i start jogging from my current location to some other location, i calculatd distnce trvelled by me but i am unable to trace path from my starting location to my finish point please tell me your suggestions .

thank you

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13599083/1032151